# Word similar to "collusion" but without negative connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a piece where multiple seemingly disparate (even *juxtaposed*, without a common mission) government organizations are combining their efforts in somewhat of an unpublicized task force.  This collaboration is not necessarily classified or secret, but it doesn't become known until when they make their bombshell announcement.

> In a rare ______ of inter-agency cooperation, ...

What is a good word to describe this sort of arrangement that doesn't have the negative connotation associated with *collusion*?

---

EDIT: I'm looking specifically to include the unpublicized/secret aspect.  Also, I'm not tied to a noun answer per se, other parts of speech are welcome as well.

Comment: What was wrong with your own word - 'collaboration' ?

Comment: @NigelJ looking to include somewhat of the quasi secrecy idea.

Comment: I cannot do better than 'a rare private collaboration...'.

Comment: @erich perhaps it's better replacing rare (maybe even rephrase the entire thing) with a word to include secrecy, perhaps: _covert_, _secluded_, e.g. _in a secluded setting, there was a rare occurrence of inter-agency cooperation_

Comment: @NigelJ 'collaboration' is certainly less negative than 'collusion', but there are still hints of negativity in contexts like WWII, like the usually anodyne 'appeasement'.

Comment: The duplicate answers do not, in my view, actually answer the OP.

Comment: 'Partnership' might be suitable.[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partnership)

Comment: In a rare *behind-the-scenes act* of inter-agency cooperation...

Comment: My first choice was the word *cabal*. In looking up its definition, many synonyms were suggested, e.g.,  clique, faction, coterie, cell, sect, junta, camarilla; lobby (group), pressure group

Answer (score 2):

[conclave](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/conclave)

> A secret or confidential meeting.

As in:

> In a rare conclave of inter-agency cooperation, ...

Comment: This usually is perfectly fine, but watch out for some bad connotations in certain contexts, like WWII.

Comment: @Mitch ... indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use furtive:

> Attempting to avoid notice or attention, typically because of guilt or a belief that discovery would lead to trouble; secretive.[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/furtive)

For example:

> a *furtive* occasion[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/occasion) of inter-agency cooperation, something which doesn't happen often...

The *furtive* is added to include some sort of secrecy. *Rare* is removed to get the emphasis on *furtive*, the function of rare can be added after a comma, that way the emphasis is on the mild secrecy.

Comment: see my edit - looking for the secrecy aspect, and doesn't have to be a noun.

Comment: @erich ... something like a conclave?

Comment: @erich updated my answer to include that